# Embed three PDF files and renders on one PDF page with custom layout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

I have a windows form project with C# to get 3 URL to different PDF's files located on my computer (each PDF has 1 page).

I want to combine them into a new PDF file with one page with a custom layout as shown on image below:

[image: Custom layout PDF]

Please, do you know any plugin or solution to archieve this problem?

Thank you in advance. Kind regards,

Joaquín

Comment: This should be possible with any general purpose PDF library. Which have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have used iTextSharp to generate single PDF and RazorPDF on ASP .NET MVC but I don’t know how to draw the output layout. I have tried also to embed PDF in HTML and then render to PDF but it creates a blank PDF. Thanks

Comment: Using iTextSharp the task is fairly easy: You create a new `Document`/`PdfWriter` pair, import the single pages from the three input documents, and arrange them on the first page of the new document using affine transformations for rotating, scaling, and moving.